# Running application from browser ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have a c# windows application that can successfully record audio using user's desktop mic.
Now i want this facility to run from ASP.NET website. (Note: user would not have this application installed on his machine). 
Is there a way that i can run this application from a web page and record and save sound file on user's desktop? I searched on google and found that it is achievable using ActiveX. But i am not sure how to do this.... :((

Any Clue...??

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to do this using standard HTML / web browser functionality.

You will need to use a richer, client-side platform like Silverlight or Flash. ActiveX could also support this, but it's a pretty dated technology. Better to go with Silverlight or Flash.