# trigger a .net application on the server from web asp.net with parsing some argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I dont know whether this is possible but it would be great if there is a solution for this:

I have an asp.net webpage. When the user opens a webpage. I would like that webpage to trigger to run a .net application running on the client machine. In addition, during that trigger, that webpage also passes some parameters as arguments to the .net application.

I hope to get some ideas how to achieve this issue somehow?

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running application from browser ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706632/running-application-from-browser-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty vague question, but you might look into either:

1. **SignalR** - a long polling library for ASP.Net that lets you make calls to client side code from the server side "faking a persistently open connection"
2. **Node.js** - a javascript library for the server-side.

I would suggest starting with SignalR

**Edit:**

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

http://chatapp.apphb.com/

Comment: SignalR seems promising. I will take a look on it. great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's good. I used it to fake a little chat room application. amazing that i can be aware of all users running my client-side code and call to each of them... for instance, when someone posts something to the server, i can call each person's client side function to render the text on their page... its rad.

Comment: yes, it sounds like what I want to do as well. You gave me a light to more forward ;)

Comment: SignalIR is just a message-passing system. It won't let you run a client-side app, which is what the original question asks.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer wao. chatapp.apphb.com is so cool, is it open source? thanks

Comment: @devn - yes it is. i posted the github link

Comment: @RickNz - you're right, it is a message passing library via long-polling. Like I said, it was a pretty vague question. I read it as a request to control an ASP.Net application (already rendered and running on the client) from the server... in which case that's exactly what SignalR is for. If the question launching a fat/smart/thin client OS-installed app from a button on a page, there's tons of other options.

Comment: @devn - did this answer solve or at least address your issue or did I misunderstand needs within your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Running application from browser ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706632/running-application-from-browser-asp-net)

In short you can't do this with HTML & JS, you may be able to with silverlight depending on what you want to do

Comment: the post more than half year ago. probably, there has been a solution solution :)

Comment: This is incorrect. There are plenty of ways, and will be more once the browsers support Web Sockets. Check SignalR and Node.js options.

Comment: fair enough, I've not really looked into them much

Comment: check it out - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR - and google their chatroom example. its online now and you can often talk with the guy(s) who are coding it. Scott Hanselman has also blogged about it and done demos on it quite a bit. - http://chatapp.apphb.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the client-side app? If so, Click Once is one approach. Silverlight is another.

For a general purpose solution, the app either needs to be registered with the browser for a specific MIME type (this is how the browser knows to start Acrobat Reader for PDF files, for example), or you would need to create and have your users install an Active-X plug-in (native C++ code, though).